# How can I store private posts and likes on Android?

Tags: android, facebook-like

I would create an Android app where the users can login with Facebook or Twitter(no problem with this) and then they can post something to give everyone that is his friends or followers, to LIKE or FAVORITE what they wrote.

The app should be like this, approximately:

1. **LOGIN** (with Facebook or Twitter)
2. Show all the **POSTS** of the others friends that has the app with **LIKES NUMBERS** next to each post.
3. Text form where they can write and publish their own posts.

Everyone that login can just put ONE like and being able to see how many likes are stored in that exact time.

The important thing is that the posts and the likes must not be shown in Facebook Diary or Twitter Account to everyone, but just to the users of my app.

I could say I want to create a little private social network with just posts (with likes and comments).

Anyone can help me?
I don't know how to store all the posts and the likes "live"...

Comment: You kind of answer your own question: 'I want to create a little private social network with just posts (with likes and comments)' -- that's what you need to do, with a web service that your Android app talks to.  Try doing that web service and come back with more specific questions.

Comment: Thanks for your replay!
Do you have some links of tutorial where I can start studying? I don't know where to start for making a web service that stores "live" data like this.